# XPath Wildcard for Numbers

Tags: html, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have some HTML I've extraced in the following format:

```
<table id="post123">
  <div id="postname">Post Name</div>
</table>
<table id="post124">
  <div id="postname">Post Name 2</div>
</table>
```

Using Xpath, I'd like to get only the elements which have "post" in them, followed by numbers.

I thought of using:

```
table[contains(@id, "post")]
```

But this will also return the element with id "postname", which is not what I want. How would you do that? Is there a wildcard in xpath for numbers?

Also note that the HTML might look like this:

```
<table id="123post">
  <div id="namepost">Post Name</div>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `matches()` instead.

Something like:

```
matches(@id,'^post\d+$')
```

**Edit** (to match `123post` or `post123`):

```
matches(@id,'^\d*post\d*$')
```

That would also match `id="post"`. If that's a problem, you could use:

```
matches(@id,'(^post\d+$|^\d+post$)')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but only if the numbers are after the letters. What would be the regex if the numbers are before the letters? And why does this not work in regexpal?

Comment: @jbkkd - I updated the regext to match both. (It would also match just `id="post"`...not sure if that's a problem.) I'm also not sure about regexpal (I used oXygen to test).